# Getting the rows that causing error or fail in Migrate

Tags: migrations

I am migrating a large csv file into drupal. I am able to do mapping and import the content into Drupal. However, I found it is difficult to get the specific record to that fail. I would be grateful if you could help me on this.

Kind Regards